# Polling events on socket and read from stdin at the same time

Tags: c, events

I have a basic client/server combination, the client is reading from stdin but i would like him to be able to poll new events from the same time from the socket, here is his principal function:

```
static int shell(cli_ctrl_t ctrl)
  {
      char **toks = NULL;
      char *line = NULL;
      size_t len = 0;
      size_t i = 0;

      getline(&line, &len, stdin);
      toks = sep_tok(line, "  \n\r\t");
      for (; commands[i].str != NULL; i++) {
          if (strcmp(commands[i].str, toks[0]) == 0) {
              commands[i].ptr(&ctrl, toks);
          }
      }
      return (0);
  }
```

I dont know how to pull events on the socket on ctrl.control_socket and at the same time read commands with getline()

Comment: Please produce a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No one knows what is ``commands``, and what is ``commands[i].ptr``

Comment: to read from several sources (socket and *stdin* in your case ) just use `select` and associated macros `FD_x`

Comment: thanks @bruno thats what i needed!

Comment: Depending on the platform you will want to use `poll` (or a similar mechanism) over `select`.